# Destroying specific user session in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, authentication, glassfish

In my page I have administrative panel for managing users.
Assume I delete or block any user and this user is already logged into my webpage.

How can I destroy his/her session?

Users log in through j_security_check
`(HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest().login(getUsername(), getPassword());`

Using:

- JSF 2.1
- Primefaces 2.2.1
- Glassfish 3.1

Answer (score 2):

You could put some "invalidated" flag in a application-level map, or in the database, and have a servlet filter check at each request that the current user's "invalidated" flag is not set.

Comment: I know, but in my opinion this is very ineffective method.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `sesssionObject.invalidate()` method to do so as follows.

```
 HttpSession session= 

(HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);

 session.invalidate();
```

---

The `invalidate()` method on a session object will destroy the current session which is going on.

Comment: This will invalidate the administrator session, not the other user's session.